# gwt blog widget for a website

Tags: gwt

Just wanted to know if anyone knows a "blog widget" in gwt that could be inserted on a website. The use case would be the following :

--> Administrator could manage himself a blog with images / rich text

--> End-users would see the blog on the side bar of the website

Thanks,

Hugues

Comment: I'm also looking for such a thing. The closest thing I've seen is http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwRichText, which is quite far from what you are asking, but at least lets you manage the rich text part.